# STOMP Selector - convert_string_expressions

Tags: activemq-classic, selector, stomp

I am using the following selector string when creating a durable subscriber.

```
(PackageCode='' OR PackageCode IS NULL) AND ( WarehouseCode LIKE '%"WHSE1"%')
```

When the subscriber is created, the selector is prefixed with `convert_string_expressions:`. Based on [the ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) it is used to automatically convert string properties to numeric ones. But my filter doesn't have a number and there is no need to have this prefix.

```
convert_string_expressions:(PackageCode='' OR PackageCode IS NULL) AND ( WarehouseCode LIKE '%"WHSE1"%')
```

I have three questions:

1. Is the selector with the prefix valid?
2. Does it hurt to have the prefix even when the condition is just string?
3. How can I suppress the prefix that is added automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector with the prefix is just as valid as it is without the prefix.

It doesn't hurt to have the prefix even when the condition is just strings. If it did hurt then it wouldn't be added automatically.

You cannot suppress the prefix that is added automatically. [It is hard-coded](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/ProtocolConverter.java#L587).